# System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101 in class and trigger

Tags: apex, soql, unit-test, governorlimits

[image]

When I run the test class I get an error as follows:

> System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101  Stack Trace: Class.UpdateUserHandler.updateUserOnAccount: line 41, column 1 Trigger.UpdateUserOnAccount: line 4, column 1

Part of Apex Class :

```
public class UpdateUserHandler {

    public static void updateUserOnAccount(Map<Id,Account> accountNewMap,Map<Id,Account> accountOldMap){
        system.debug('working');
        set<Id> freezUserIdSet = new Set<Id>(); // set to store id of user need to freez
        set<Id> unFreezUserIdSet = new Set<Id>(); // set to store id of user need to unfreez
        Set<Id> userIdSet = new Set<Id>(); //to store all user id need to update
        System.debug(accountNewMap.keySet());
        for(User usr : [Select Id,Name,ContactId,Contact.Disable__c,Contact.AccountId From User where ContactId In (Select Id from Contact where AccountId In: accountNewMap.keySet())]){
            System.debug('usr = ' + usr);
            System.debug('usr.Contact.AccountId = ' + usr.Contact.AccountId);
            Account accNew = accountNewMap.get(usr.Contact.AccountId);
            Account accOld = accountOldMap.get(usr.Contact.AccountId);
            System.debug('accNew  = ' + accNew );
            System.debug('accOld  = ' + accOld );
            System.debug('accOld  = ' + accOld );
            if(accNew.Activate_Customer_Community__c != accOld.Activate_Customer_Community__c){//chacked Activate Customer Community is changed or not
                System.debug('1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111' );
                if(accNew.Activate_Customer_Community__c){// if  Activate Customer Community is set to checked 
                    System.debug('222222222222222222222222222222222222' );
                    if(!usr.Contact.Disable__c){          // if contact status is not desable then unfreez the related user
                        System.debug('33333333333333333333333333333' );
                        unFreezUserIdSet.add(usr.id);
                        userIdSet.add(usr.id);
                    }
                }
                else{                                   // if  Activate Customer Community is set to unchecked 
                    System.debug('44444444444444444444444' );
                    //if(usr.Contact.Disable__c){         // if contact status is desable then freez the related user
                        System.debug('555555555555555555555555555555' );
                        freezUserIdSet.add(usr.id);
                        userIdSet.add(usr.id);
                    //}
                }
            }
        }
        System.debug('freezUserIdSet = ' + freezUserIdSet );
        System.debug('unFreezUserIdSet = ' + unFreezUserIdSet );
        System.debug('userIdSet = ' + userIdSet );
        List<UserLogin> userLoginUpdateList = new List<UserLogin>(); //list to update freez status of user
        for(UserLogin usrLogin : [Select Id,UserId,IsFrozen from UserLogin where userId In: userIdSet]){
            if(usrLogin.isFrozen && unFreezUserIdSet.contains(usrLogin.userId)){ // if user status is freez and we need to unfreez that user then 
                usrLogin.isFrozen = false;
                userLoginUpdateList.add(usrLogin);
            }
            if(!usrLogin.isFrozen && freezUserIdSet.contains(usrLogin.userId)){ // if user status is unfreez and we need to freez that user then
                usrLogin.isFrozen = true;
                userLoginUpdateList.add(usrLogin);
            }
        }
        if(!userLoginUpdateList.isEmpty()){ //if user login list is not empty
            update userLoginUpdateList;
        }  
    }
```

The Error Line is :

```
  for(UserLogin usrLogin : [Select Id,UserId,IsFrozen from UserLogin where userId In: userIdSet]){
```

Apex Trigger :

```
trigger UpdateUserOnAccount on Account (after update) {
    if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate){
        system.debug('before');
        UpdateUserHandler.updateUserOnAccount(Trigger.newMap, Trigger.OldMap);
        system.debug('after');
    }
}
```

The Error :

```
UpdateUserHandler.updateUserOnAccount(Trigger.newMap, Trigger.OldMap);
```

Part of Test Class :

```
static testMethod void TestConversionsNoOpp() 
    {
        Account genericaccount = new Account(Name = 'someaccount');
        insert genericaccount;

            Lead ld1 = new Lead(Company='colead1',LastName='colead1');
            Lead ld2 = new Lead(Company='colead2',LastName='colead2');
            ld2.OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId();
            Campaign cam = new Campaign(Name='campname');
            insert cam;
            insert ld1;
            insert ld2;
            CampaignMember mc1 = new CampaignMember(CampaignId = cam.Id, LeadId=ld1.Id, Buyer__c='a', user__c='b');
            CampaignMember mc2 = new CampaignMember(CampaignId = cam.Id, LeadId=ld2.Id, Buyer__c='a', user__c='b');
            List<CampaignMember> cms = new List<CampaignMember>();
            cms.add(mc1);
            cms.add(mc2);

            insert cms;
            List<Id> cmids = new List<id>();
            /*for(CampaignMember thiscm: cms)
            {
              cmids.add(thiscm.id);
            }*/

        ld1.admin_CMSourceId__c = mc1.id;
        update ld1;  // Needed later to simulate the button click on conversion
        ld2.admin_CMSourceId__c = mc2.id;
        update ld2; // Needed later to simulate the button click on conversion

        // Initialize the opp for later creation from CampaignMember
        Opportunity Opp = new Opportunity(CloseDate = Date.Today().addDays(30), AccountId = genericaccount.Id,
            Name='someopp', StageName='Selected' );

            mc1.Response_Status__c = 'Working';
            mc2.Response_Status__c = 'Disqualified';
            mc2.Disqualified_Reason__c = 'no budget';


            update cms;

            // We're checking CampaignMemberOpportunityInsertTrigger here
            Opp.admin_CMSourceId__c = mc2.Id;  // Set the source ID
            insert Opp;

            Test.StartTest();


            // Now let's do a lead convert
         Database.LeadConvert lc = new database.LeadConvert();
        lc.setLeadId(ld2.Id);
        lc.setConvertedStatus('Converted - Existing Opportunity');
        lc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(true);
        lc.setOwnerId(UserInfo.getUserId());
        Database.LeadConvertResult lcr2 = Database.convertLead(lc);

              Test.StopTest();    
            try
            {
             }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
              System.Debug('Exception during TestConversionsNoOpp StopTest (async error)' + ex.getMessage());
            }

         System.assert(lcr2.isSuccess());
            CampaignMember mc2b = [Select Id,Response_Status__c, Opportunity_Create_Date__c, Opportunity_Name__c, Buyer__c, User__c from CampaignMember where Id = :mc2.id];
        Lead convertedleadinfo = [Select Id, isConverted, Status from Lead where id = :ld2.Id];
        System.Debug('original leadid:' + ld2.Id + ' leadid result id:' + lcr2.getLeadId());
        System.Debug('Converted lead isconverted:' + convertedleadinfo.IsConverted + ' status:' + convertedleadinfo.Status);
           system.assertEquals('Converted - Existing Opportunity', mc2b.Response_Status__c);


     }



}
```

Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: what are debug logs during this test run? I am not able to see any issues with code yet

Comment: @ kurunve:Thanks for your response.While deploying a trigger ...it throws an error .PFA screen shot .I get error for the  test classes .Where one test class has a class and two triggers ,Where i have shared only part of the codes.Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that there are no more triggers for account object? And about logs  -- I mean debug logs, not test logs

Comment: @kurunve  :Their are 'n' no of triggers and classes on Account and v use few packages even those have the triggers nd classes.

Comment: @SalesforceCRMAccountCRM you might need to optimize your triggers on other objects that is being executed on your test class. Even if the error has occurred on the account trigger, it doesn't mean that it is the one that's accumulating heaps of SOQL queries. 

Try checking the debug logs and check the different trigger that is being fired when your running your test class. There should be a section on the debug logs like this "Number of SOQL queries: 0 out of 100" which specifies the number of SOQL queries that is being accumulated per trigger that is being executed.

Comment: Maybe you should try to make your class asynchronous (https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Asynchronous_Processing_in_Force_com) by using global class UpdateUserHandler and the annotation @future on your method.